# Need Logical elaboration over invoking / calling the instance of a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, object

I am a learner and I need some explanation over when to invoke or to simply call an instance of a module e.g.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
```

here, we have invoked the `Router()`, but some cases we do not invoke the instance e.g.

```
const redux = require('redux');
const createStore = redux.createStore;
```

where we did not invoke `createStore`. Could you please help me understand. (please ignore `createStore` as it says it is now deprecated. I took it as an example )

Comment: You can call the instance whenever you need it. can you please clarify your question?

Comment: @EhabReda : I just need to know the logic behind in between when to simply call the instance without invoking and when to invoke it. As per above examples, we have invoked Router() but not createStore.

Comment: I think it is just the way the modules and packages were designed by their developers.

Comment: @Jatin : I guess there has to be some analogy. Let's wait for what other experts says about it :::